# What can lock google bot out

Tags: php, curl, webserver, googlebot

Google bot crawls our website weird, some pages are blocked and others are not by robots.txt
If you use the google mobile friendly test, then css and js files and images are randomly blocked with *"other reason"*. Sometimes you have to retry the page self in the test.

The user doesn't see anything when visiting our site, I think only when you are a bot or use curl. And if it happens it doesn't always happen.

The site is made of a **WordPress** installation and some *lonely PHP files* and a *coppermine gallery*. But all pages have problems, not always but randomly I guess.

- Example lonely page: https://www.woefkesranch.be/puppies-te-koop/shiba-inu-puppies-te-koop.php
- Example wordpress page: https://www.woefkesranch.be/hondenrassen/
- Example coppermine gallery: https://www.woefkesranch.be/gallery/index.php?cat=4

What could be the reason?

Edit: my PHP version is 5.6

Comment: As a sidenote, loading any one of those web pages takes more than 10 seconds if the site wasn't cached earlier. Google might just time out and cite it as 'other reason'

Comment: what could be the reason for the timeout? i see in php log sometimes mod_proxy_fcgi.c(954): (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 61.191.220.250:40684] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :

Comment: and another repeating php error:    mod_proxy_fcgi.c(666): [client 177.135.101.5:56240] AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header